# startActivity runs but activity is not shown on Xiaomi Redmi Note 4

Tags: android, android-intent, appcompatactivity

My app has a service and an activity. From the service, on some triggers, activity is called with following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

On my test phones (mostly Samsung, Lenovo and Huawei)  , activity starts and is displayed on the phone screen with its layout.
However, on Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 with Android 7, activity layout is not displayed.
I only see the following line on logcat:

> I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:281438674 intent:Intent { flg=0x30000000 cmp=com.test.app/.MainActivity }

The activity class extends AppCompatActivity , but I also tried with a normal activity class (same layout) and the result did not change.

activity is defined like below in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

There is no exception or other error/warning on log. So I am not able to troubleshoot further.
What can I do ?

Comment: what is the purpose of the 2 addFlags?

Comment: their purpose is to remain only 1 instance and to be on top of other activities. But I also tried without those flags. The result was same. Activity is never seen.

Comment: here is a best solution given by user [Redirect to your activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239077/miui-10-doesnt-let-service-start-activity-xiaomi-redmi-note)