# Detect Android devices which disallow opening Activity from background

Tags: android

My Android app needs to open Activity from the background. It works well on many devices. However, I found that it does not work on some specific devices.

Turns out, these devices have special permission in the Setting page of my app, which can be `Display pop-up windows while running in the background` on some devices, or `Start in the background` on some other devices, or something else on other devices where I haven't discovered yet. This permission should be enabled for my app.

My question is how to detect these kinds of devices so I can open the Setting page of the app and ask the user to enable the required permission.

Related question:

- [MIUI 10 doesn't let service start activity - Xiaomi Redmi Note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239077/miui-10-doesnt-let-service-start-activity-xiaomi-redmi-note)