# MIUI 11 preventing Activities (of other apps) being launched from foreground service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-popupwindow, miui

In some recent MIUI 11 update, it seems no longer possible to launch an `Activity` (at least, of another app) from a System Alert Window (SAW) running in a `Foreground Service`. I can confirm on my MIUI 11.0.5 device (not sure about earlier versions of MIUI 11) and from reports in the wild. This was all working fine a couple of months ago.

I've tested using (with and without the flag):

```
Intent intent = viewContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(otherPackageName);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // doesn't make a difference
viewContext.startActivity(intent)
```

called from a `OnClickListener` on the main `View` of the SAW.

Logcat shows that the system is getting the intent:

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:6329289 intent:Intent...
```

But nothing actually happens. I noticed calls to a `ContentProvider` on the other app, work as expected. I even tried starting the activity from within that `ContentProvider`, but that also did not work.

Perhaps, more generally, the issue is starting `Activities` (of other apps) from non-`Activity` `Contexts`.

Note: although it seems like the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239077/miui-10-doesnt-let-service-start-activity-xiaomi-redmi-note), the accepted workaround does not apply in this case. Both apps have "Display pop-up windows while running in the background" permission enabled.

Any ideas?